# How to do batch file conversion with face recognition in Windows Live Photo Gallery?

Tags: software, metadata, batch

I have a large number of files I want to convert from RAW to JPG. I want to copy the facial recognition data along with the other metadata. I know I can do batch conversion in other applications, but that won't give the facial metadata unless I do the conversion in Windows Live Photo Gallery (WLPG). I don't believe WLPG has a batch conversion facility. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it the WLPG face recognition essential or would you be open to another application which does its own recognition and also has a batch mode?

Comment: That would be fine if the recognition were better than WLPG's! It took me a long time to get them right.

Answer (score 1):

You could investigate some free automation software eg http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

You can script a lot of windows activities using this software - Its not for the faint hearted - we have used it at work. Always think of the trade off between time to develop a script vs time to do the job manually